# How to change the logo in oracle apex based on user logged into the application

Tags: oracle-apex

(application on apex.oracle.com - version 4.2.3)

I would like to change the logo of the application based on the user logged in. How can I add a condition to achieve this.

Example: I have a `user` table and `user_type` as a column in that, if `user_type` is `"client"` I would like to show him one logo & if the `user_type` is `"super_user"` I would like to show another logo on the logged in home.

Comment: Based on the user or user**s**? What version of apex are you using?

Comment: I created a workspace in apex.oracle.com and doing an web-application in it. and Yes, based on type of user logged in, I would like to change the logo in the logged in home. Example: I have a user table and user_type as a column in that, if "client" type is the user_type I would like to show him one logo & if the user_type is "super_user" I would like to show another logo on the logged in home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the logo by going to:

> application properties - user interface - logo

or

> shared components - user interface - user interface properties - logo

You can define the type of logo there. When choosing "Image" you can specify the url to the image in the "Logo" text item. In there you can use substitution syntax to make this a bit more dynamic. Eg, I could use `&APP_USER.` to construct a link like this:

```
#IMAGE_PREFIX#custom/&APP_USER._logo.png
```

[image: Edit logo attributes]

The follow-up to this would be: how can I get my user type in there?
I'd advise to create an application item, eg `AI_USER_TYPE`. To make sure there is always a value in it I'd be inclined to specify a post-authentication function for your current authentication scheme (shared components - security - authentication schemes). This'll guarantee the item will be correctly filled in once the user has logged in. 
[image: add a post authentication procedure to auth scheme]

Comment: thanks @Tom i'm checking it, and will approach u if found any doubts

Comment: I have created two authorization schemes' in my application. One is in general for all users & another is for users who have a particular kind of user_access_level. Is there a way we can show different logo's based on this authorization schemes? If so can u show me how can we do that. Thanks in advance..

Comment: @xyz9999 One way to try to do this is by changing the post-authentication code to check the authorization by using [apex_util.public_check_authorization](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_util.htm#CHDJHBFJ). If one returns true, set an application item to a certain string, and use the application item in the logo url. Another completely different way would be to change the page template and put a region in the html where the logo also is. On page 0 you can then assign a region there, and create multiple with authorization checks.